# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng()

Tags: php, module, gd

That is the error message that I get on my php error log.

So far, I know that the GD library is the problem, it's not installed ( I think is not installed but it was working before in my server and now is not so I don't know what happened but I want to assume that is not installed).

I checked if the module was installed by running `php -m` and gd doesn't show up, also `phpinfo()` doesn't show anything related to gd.
I installed php on a CentOS server 5.9 with remi repo. Now, the problem is that I can't just run `yum install php-gd` because it won't have any effect since it was installed manually. Any ideas on how can I install just that module to my php installation?

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: PHP 5.5.17 (cli) (built: Sep 20 2014 16:59:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group

Comment: The doco says GD is bundled with PHP since 4.3.6. Sounds like you'd have to go out of your way to not install it. Is there a `gd.so` file in your PHP extensions dir? Maybe you just need `extension=gd.so` in your `php.ini` file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had to install the php-gd library with the remi repo enabled
So if anybody has the same problem here it is: 
`yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55`

Comment: For openSuSE (which uses the php version number in their package names), this is `zypper install php5-gd`